# Creating code for anaylist

Tags: vba, macros

I am developing a program in analyzing data. I am very new to Visual Basics and Macros. I have 2 columns A and B that has values between .001 and 1. I need help creating bins to store these numbers. I've done research and looked at so many example programs, nothing remotely close to what I need. 
Here're a few important details. Column A has needed data from A1 to A2625 and column B has needed data from B1 to B2700. I need to put this data in into 10 bins. Ex: Bin 1 needs to hold values .001 to .11, Bin 2- .12-.20.....until bin 10. Any suggestions? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you'll create a macro that is something along the lines of

```
Option Explicit
Sub myMacro()
    Dim nRow As Integer
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim endRowColumn1 As Integer
    Dim endRowColumn2 As Integer

    Set wSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    endRowColumn1 = wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    endRowColumn2 = wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Clear results from last run
    wSht.Range("C:E").Clear ' Clear rows 3,4,5
    wSht.Cells(1, 3) = "Bin1"
    wSht.Cells(1, 4) = "Bin2"
    wSht.Cells(1, 5) = "No Criteria Met"


    ' STARTING WITH SECOND ROW
    For nRow = 2 To endRowColumn1 ' For each row... to the end of your rows..
      ' If the first bin criteria is met...
      If (wSht.Cells(nRow, 1) >= 0.001) And _
      (wSht.Cells(nRow, 1) < 0.12) Then
        ' Then put the value into the first bin. (column C)
        wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wSht.Cells(nRow, 1)
      ElseIf (wSht.Cells(nRow, 1) >= 0.12) And _
      (wSht.Cells(nRow, 1) < 0.2) Then
        ' Then put the value into the second bin. (column D)
        wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wSht.Cells(nRow, 1)
      Else ' No Criteria Met
        wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wSht.Cells(nRow, 1)
      End If
    Next nRow

    For nRow = 2 To endRowColumn2 ' For each row... to the end of your rows..
      ' If the first bin criteria is met...
      If (wSht.Cells(nRow, 2) >= 0.001) And _
      (wSht.Cells(nRow, 2) < 0.12) Then
        ' Then put the value into the bin. (column C)
        wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wSht.Cells(nRow, 2)
      ElseIf (wSht.Cells(nRow, 2) >= 0.12) And _
      (wSht.Cells(nRow, 2) < 0.2) Then
        ' Then put the value into the second bin. (column D)
        wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wSht.Cells(nRow, 2)
      Else ' No Criteria Met
        wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = wSht.Cells(nRow, 2)
      End If
    Next nRow

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have questions about the code and we can discuss it.

Comment: Can you help me understand. If I were to do a program similar would this put both columns in the bins or would I have to do it per column. And will I need to designate a row/column to store or create these bins? I just got to this part and got stuck.

Comment: This particular program I wrote only does the first column. So you'd need another IF statement for another column and another IF statement for another bin. You will need to designate a column to store these bins. You can make the code for column B by copying the entire "for" loop and replacing the endRow value as well as changing the nRow,1 to nRow,2 and then nRow,3 to nRow,4. Additionally, I do not delete the 'blanks' from the bins column. But you can always do that later.

Comment: Also, side note, do you know that you can easily create a Histogram using the AnalysisToolPak ? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-histogram-B6814E9E-5860-4113-BA51-E3A1B9EE1BBE --- I don't know your end goal of these bins.

Comment: My goal with the bins is to calculate the frequencies of each occurrence, then average the percentage. Then I have a second excel similar that I'll do the same to, then graph the outcome. with bins on the x-axis and percentage on the y-axis. That's the goal but this is different than any programming I've ever done. So, all suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I think I understand. I would take a look at the AnalysisToolPak Histogram tool, but the y-axis won't be percentages, just count.   I've updated my code (the <1 was wrong, it should have been <.11) --- and I've added how you would deal with column B (column2)  -- I've also changed how the program places the number in the bins .Cells(3,nRow) became .Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp) which effectively gets the next empty row in column 3

Comment: Thank you so much. Out of curiosity could I use dynamic range so it'll automatically use the information in the column instead of manually inserting what cell the column ends? I only ask because each spreadsheet differes. I may be incorrect though.

Comment: Yes you could. Use .cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row to get the last row of column one, for instance.

Comment: invalid next control variable reference error code??

Comment: Whoops, next endRowColumn1 and endRowColumn2 should be next nRow, I don't know why I changed it earlier. The error is stating that the "for loop" 'next' variable is invalid. (And it was)

Comment: I changed the code. Enter data into columns 1 and 2 with a header in row 1 --- and you should be able to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do this. There is a function in Excel called [Frequency](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FREQUENCY-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9). If you have numbers in one columns you make your bins in another column like this

```
+--------+------+
| values | bins |
+--------+------+
|     59 |    0 |
|     16 |   10 |
|     12 |   20 |
|      5 |   30 |
|     33 |   40 |
|     90 |   50 |
|     92 |   60 |
|     74 |   70 |
|     26 |   80 |
|     63 |   90 |
|     40 |  100 |
|     etc|      |
+--------+------+
```

then you can use

```
FREQUENCY(values,bins)
```

I needs to be entered exactly like this though because it is an array formula:

[image]

Notice I have all of the cells adjacent to the bins selected and I am in edit mode in the top cell. Then once the formula is written you hit ctrl+alt+enter and all the cells you selected will fill in with the number of occurrences for that bin.

This will work with multiple columns.

To make a histogram graph bins v frequency.

What this won't do is create bins for you.

Comment: I am aware of how to achieve this through excel. The complicaion is that I need everything programed so it could do the funtion automatically